# Create multiple records using strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie to Ruby/Rails world and I have the following problem that I'm struggle to make it work.

I have the following sample structure of json data which I'm trying to save in database.

```
{ "new_contacts"=>
[{"given_name"=>"John", "family_name"=>"Doe", "cell"=>"123456", "country_code"=>"IT"}, 
{"given_name"=>"Sara", "family_name"=>"Peti", "cell"=>"221214", "country_code"=>"IT"}] }
```

Now inside my controller I have the following code to process this json data and try to save them.

```
def multi_create
  results =  @contact_book.contacts.create(new_contacts_params)
end
  
def new_contacts_params
  params.require(:new_contacts).permit([ :given_name, :family_name, :cell, :country_code ])
end
```

I have tried many combinations but with no luck. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See here for a discussion: https://codersloth.medium.com/rails-creating-multiple-records-from-a-single-request-a45261085164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To permit nested keys in array and require parent key you can use

```
params
  .permit(new_contacts: %i[given_name family_name cell country_code])
  .require(:new_contacts)
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem. Thanks a lot my friend. I really appreciated it